# vue3 + element-plus dynamic add form item validate falied

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

I occured a problem with inline rules in element-plus(vue3) form item. Following is the code I had writed.

```
<el-form
   ref="packFormRef"
   :model="packForm"
    label-width="80px"
    class="add-app-dialog"
    status-icon
 > 
  <div v-for="(item, index) in packForm.packages" :key="index">
    <div v-show="index !== 0" class="segerate"></div>
    <el-form-item 
            label="name"
            :prop="'name.' + index + '.value'"
            :rules="{
              required: true,
              message: 'name cannot empty',
              trigger: 'blur',
            }"
          >
            <el-input v-model="item.name" placeholder="please input name" />
          </el-form-item>
          <el-form-item 
            label="os" 
            :prop="'item.' + index + '.os'"
            :rules="{required: true, message: 'description is required', trigger: 'blur'}"
          >
            <el-input v-model="item.os" placeholder="please input os" />
            <div class="btn-ground">
              <el-icon
                v-show="index !== 0"
                class="email-btn"
                @click.prevent="
                  packForm.packages.length != 1 && removeRow(item)
                "
              >
                <Delete />
              </el-icon>
              <el-icon
                v-show="index + 1 == packForm.packages.length"
                class="email-btn"
                @click="addRow"
              >
                <Plus />
              </el-icon>
            </div>
          </el-form-item>
   </div>
</el-form>
```

I have test few methods to fixed this problem. But it didn't work.
Hope you can give me some suggestion.
And Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please give a detailed description of the problem.  Describe expected vs. actual result.  Explain your code, point out where the problem is, explain what you're trying to do, etc. You say you tried some methods to fix the problem.  Show what you tried.  Explain the attempts and results of those attempts as well.  Just saying there's an error and pasting some code isn't helpful.